# '+' lost from input on form submission

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an input:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ReleaseErrors", "ManageReleases", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="@ViewBag.Name" />
    <button type="submit" onclick="checkInput()">Add</button>
}
```

And I am getting the value:

```
 string ReleaseName = Request.Form["name"];
```

However if it contains any '+' characters they get lost (simply missing).

I also have this problem with links:

`<button onclick="location.href='/ManageReleases/Update?name=@r.Name'">Update</button>`

The html contains the + characters but they don't get submitted.

How can I overcome this?

Comment: What's the rendered html for the input control?  (view-source in browser)

Comment: How is this being sent to the server-side (C#) code?

Comment: @freedomn-m if you haven't notice from `Request.Form["name"]` via form submit

Comment: No, `Request.Form["name"]` is how you read it once it's been sent.  You've updated the question to confirm that's it's sent via Html.BeginForm and `FormMethod.Post`.  This means that part is not a UrlEncode issue, which it would have been if you sent it on the querystring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used was to format the string correctly:

```
r.Name.Replace("+", "%2B").Replace(" ", "%20")
```

This will result in the correct urls.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `checkInput` just does what it says (checks input) then there's nothing immediately obvious and trying to recreate (hidden input, post, Request.Form) does not reproduce your issue - so it's possible it's somewhere else in your solution (eg web.config)

Can you create a new, simple solution to try and reproduce it?

The additional, second part:

```
<button onclick="location.href='/ManageReleases/Update?name=@r.Name'">Update</button>
```

definitely needs to be url encoded

```
<button onclick="location.href='/ManageReleases/Update?name=@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(r.Name)'">Update</button>
```